# File uploading is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code-igniter to upload files with two input boxes . 
But my code not uploading both the files i m getting same file two times.

please take a look my code -:

```
**//html**

<?php echo form_open_multipart('vipul/do_upload');?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile1' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
<?php echo "</form>"?>
```

in controller

```
public function do_upload(){

    foreach ($_FILES as $keys=>$values){

        if($keys == 'userfile1'){
            $config = array(
                        'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                        'overwrite' => false,
                        'max_size' => "20480000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                        'max_height' => "768000",
                        'max_width' => "1024000"
                        );
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload())
                { $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());}
                else{   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); }
        }

        if($keys == 'userfile'){
            $config = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                'overwrite' => false,
                'max_size' => "20480000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "768000",
                'max_width' => "1024000"
                );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload())
            {   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());  }
            else{   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try with `$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)`

Comment: $field_name holds which value ??

Comment: that's you field name `userfile` or `userfile1`

Comment: In case `$keys == 'userfile1'` use `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')` and for `$keys == 'userfile' use $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your PHP code and try this out

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to

```
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

where `$field_name` is your input name attribute.

please check [CodeIgniter's File Uploading Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)